# How to add a new grid item or image to the already built Grid View images basd Flutter application with a Floating Action Button

Tags: grid, flutter-layout

I have a 12 grid items Flutter application with grid view. I have a floating Action Buttion in that grid View Ui . Now with a  Tap on Flating Action Buttopn I want to add a new Grid Item and it should be shown in the Grid View and now the count should be 13 Grid Items for example.

My code is as follows

```
    List<ItemModel> items = [
  //These will have separate page
  ItemModel(item: "", icon: Icons.smartphone, page: MobilesPage()),
  ItemModel(
      item: "", icon: Icons.headset, page: MobileAccessoriesPage()),
  ItemModel(item: "", icon: Icons.computer, page: ComputerPage()),
  ItemModel(item: "", icon: Icons.tv, page: TVPage()),

  // These will use the next page
  ItemModel(item: "", icon: Icons.local_laundry_service, page: LargeAppPage()),
  ItemModel(item: "", icon: Icons.kitchen, page: KitchenApplsPage()),
  ItemModel(item: "", icon: Icons.home, page: HomeApplsPage()),
  ItemModel(item: "", icon: Icons.devices_other, page: HomeEntSysPage()),
  ItemModel(item: "", icon: Icons.headset_mic,page: HeadphonesPage()),
  ItemModel(item: "", icon: Icons.photo_camera,page:CamerasPage()),
  ItemModel(item: "", icon: Icons.speaker,page:SpeakersPage()),
  ItemModel(item: "", icon: Icons.camera_roll,page:CamAccrsPage()),
];



class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}




class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1;
    return Scaffold(


      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        title: new Text("Grid View",style:
        TextStyle(fontSize: 20), textAlign: TextAlign.center),

      ),

      body: Center(
          child: GridView.count(
            primary: false,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 1,
            children: items
                .map(
                  (item) => Container(
                //  color: Colors.cyan[100],
                child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      if (item.page != null) {
                        //Navigate to the Page you have
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => item.page,
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        //Use the NextPage and pass in the model
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => NextPage(model: item),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 2,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      //color: Colors.cyan[100],
                      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Icon(item.icon, size: 90),
                          SizedBox(height: 20),
                          Text(item.item,
                              style:
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 14.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold ),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
            )
                .toList(),
          )),

      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            items.add(Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),

            ));
          });
        },
      ),


          ],
        ),
      ),

      //
    );
  }
}
class ItemModel {
  String item;
  IconData icon;
  Widget page;
  ItemModel({this.item, this.icon, this.page});
}
```

**Error :**  **The argument type '**Container**' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ItemModel'. Open documentation**

Please look    at **items.add(Container(**

Answer (score 0):

Atlast I have fixed it and  is working successfully.
Now I am able to add new Grid Item or Container to the Grid View.

Just change   at the Conatiner place`
Complete Code is as follows:

```
 floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
           
items.add(ItemModel(
            item: "Mobiles", icon: Icons.smartphone
        ));
          });
        },
      ),

         ],
        ),
      ),

      //
    );
  }
}
class ItemModel {
  String item;
  IconData icon;
  Widget page;
  ItemModel({this.item, this.icon, this.page});
}
```